# C# How to commit a TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, textbox

In a form, I have a TextBox Binding an Object on its member property "Title". Along with it is a "Save" button to test the binding.

Seems like the underlying object property does not get updated unless the textbox loses focus. But there no form.ActiveControl.Blur() for use. Besides, this does not seem like a sound hack.

Anyway to do this better? Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry for not being clear. My question is in the title: "How to commit a TextBox". I use the term "commit" from the DataGridView commit and BindingSource commit. And it's in WinForms. (Have never worked with WPF, so it didn't occur to me. Sorry).

The actual scenario I have is I have a bunch of TextBox binded to property of a single Object. The user enters values in all the TextBox and when the user clicks save (toolbar button), the last TextBox is still in focus (or in editing mode) hence the save will not capture the last value in the last textbox.

I want to find the correct way to "commit" the textbox value just before saving.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: What would a `Blur` method do? It's not clear what you're asking here. *Something* always has to have the focus. Do you just want to know how to change the focus from a textbox to another control on your form?

Comment: please elaborate , what u really wanna accomplish here

Comment: What I am asking is in the Title: How to commit a TextBox (value). Kindly see my edited post. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question has been updated to indicate this is WinForms, you'll need to handle things a little differently than if this were a WPF application. Fortunately, it turns out that the solution is very simple.

Whenever the user clicks on the "Save" button (so, say, in your Save button's `Click` event handler), **you need to call the `EndEdit` method on your `BindingSource`**. This will cause all pending changes to be committed to the underlying data source, exactly what you were hoping to accomplish.

Also see the [relevant documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.endedit.aspx) on MSDN for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Cody. I am using BindlingList instead of BindingSource (because BindSource belongs to the Forms namespace, and I don't want to pollute the Logic layer with that) and with your help I managed to find the function this.ActiveControl.DataBindings["Text"].WriteValue();

Comment: @Jake: That makes sense. Right after I posted that, I realized I was making the assumption that you were using `BindingSource`. Your question didn't actually specify how you were handling the databinding. I'm glad you were able to find the solution you needed.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like WPF from the problem description..

You want to change the binding so that it updates when the property value changes instead of when the textbox loses focus (which is the default when binding to TextBox.Text). You can do this by setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property on your binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Bubblewrap. Looks like it doesn't matter if it is WPF. The architecture is similar. Kindly see my edited post for details. For your help.